# IntelliJ 13 Tomcat Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I'm attempting to run a Java/Spring/Hibernate/Ivy application using IntelliJ 13 and its built in Tomcat deployment plugin. I'm using Tomcat 8.0.9, but I've also attempted this using Tomcat 6.0.39. I'm creating an artifact when I attempt to spin up Tomcat; a exploded war to be more specific. I'm using Ivy to resolve my dependencies and this is because it's a legacy app that doesn't use Maven. Stupid, I know.

When attempting to run this application from inside of IntelliJ using any version of Tomcat I recieve the following messages in my 'Server' log:

```
C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\bin\catalina.bat run
[2014-07-01 05:33:09,056] Artifact Kiosk:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\{username}\.IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Kiosk_4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\bin\bootstrap.jar"
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57131', transport: 'socket'
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Apps\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39;C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.1-bin\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\dev\SlikSvn\bin;.;;.;;.
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 475 ms
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 97 ms
Connected to server
[2014-07-01 05:33:10,133] Artifact Kiosk:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2014-07-01 05:33:10,479] Artifact Kiosk:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
```

My Tomcat Localhost Log looks like this:

```
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

And my Tomcat Catalina Log looks like this:

```
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Apps\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\apache-tomcat-6.0.39;C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.1-bin\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\dev\SlikSvn\bin;.;;.;;.
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 475 ms
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 97 ms
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 01, 2014 5:33:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
```

This is where those listeners are declared in my web.xml

```
<!-- Spring log4j listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener> 
  <!-- Spring bootstrap listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  
  <!-- Spring cleanup listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

All of those classes are available on my classpath, but the problem seems to be that they're not available on Tomcat's classpath.

After attempting to add my Ivy cache to the catalina.properties file under the 'shared.loader' property, in an effort to make those jars available to Tomcat's classpath, I was unable to format the directory correctly. Supposedly that would make the necessary jars available to Tomcat, and of course Tomcat doesn't provide documentation on the necessary syntax for specifying a shared loader... Help...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar problem, or at least the exception

```
30-Aug-2014 20:31:12.044 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
```

The issue was that the libs had not been added to the Artifacts.

To Fix, `File` -> `Project Structure`

then click Fix on all the errors that have been found, then click ok.

Next time I ran the projects I encountered no errors.

Comment: no such button or link labelled : Fix on all the errors ? How to fix

Comment: There should be a `Fix...` button next to the error in the Project Structure page. Although this solution is from quite a while ago there is a chance that intellij have changed the Project Structure page

see @saneryee response with the screenshot.

Comment: This was helpful. Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Add jar into Project Settings-Libraries
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue: When I build with maven, it ran well, but there was an error when running in the IDE by tomcat.

I think it is because **the IDE cannot copy jar libraries to output folder**, ie..WEB-INF/lib/ 
[image: check this folder] check it

For me (*a lazy method*), just copy the missing jars to `webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`            *[ps: under the development directory, not the output one]*